# XCode 4.3 build and debug iOS 5.0 project

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

How do I build and debug app for ios 5.0 on xcode 4.3. When I run xcode-build, it builds with xcode 4.2 adn app crashes, but when I open xcode, it builds (compiles) with xcode 4.3. Build settings -> Base SDK there is only iOS 5.1 and some MACOSX variants.

Comment: Why are you keeping Xcode4.2 around?

Comment: Well suppose I need to support older IOS versions as well.

Comment: How is that connected to leaving an outdated and buggy compiler around? Why not simply sym-linking the iOS5 SDK into Xcode4.3's SDK-folders?

Answer (score 0):

Consider specifying the xcodebuild path manually which is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild` for the Xcode 4.3.

I believe for you it's trying to launch the tool from `/Developer/usr/bin/` and finds the Xcode 4.2 tool version.

You will want to install the 5.0 Simulator SDK for Xcode 4.3 with Settings-Downloads-Components.